# libevent sent DNS request with mixed cases

Tags: c, dns, libevent

Making a connection using libevent, the strange thing is that DNS request sent was for host "WWw.yahoo.COM".   Here is the code snippet that caused it.

```
struct evhttp_connection * evcon = evhttp_connection_base_bufferevent_new(
        base, dns_base, bev,    "www.yahoo.com", port);
```

It doesn't seem to cause any problems on my application, just wonder if there is a reason why libevent needs to mix up the cases.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a security feature.

> randomize-case:INT
>   If nonzero, we randomize the case on outgoing DNS requests and make sure that replies have the same case as our requests. This so-called "0x20 hack" can help prevent some otherwise simple active events against DNS. Defaults to 1.

http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-book/Ref9_dns.html

If you would want to you can disable it using:

```
evdns_base_set_option(base, "randomize-case", "0");
```

Comment: Thanks @jahaja! This helps. Wish there is no random case by default, Least Surprise principle :-)